# confused on uniqueness in permutation calculation

Tags: c++, algorithm

Working on below problem as an algorithm puzzle. Referred a few similar solutions (and post one of them below), tried and they worked. The question is, for the line "swap(num[i], num[k]);", how do we ensure we could always swap to a number which never tried before (e.g. suppose we swap 1 with 2 in current iteration of the for loop, then it is possible later we swap 2 back with 1 in next iterations of the same for loop of the same level/layer of recursive call)? I have the confusion since we pass num by reference, and it is very possible later (lower level/layer) recursive calls modify content of num, which cause numbers we already evaluated swap back. However, I tried and it works for all of my test cases. Wondering if below solution is 100% correct, or happened to pass my test cases? :)

Here are detailed problem statement and code I am debugging,

Given a collection of numbers that might contain duplicates, return all possible unique permutations.

For example,
[1,1,2] have the following unique permutations:
[1,1,2], [1,2,1], and [2,1,1]

```
class Solution {
public:
    void recursion(vector<int> num, int i, int j, vector<vector<int> > &res) {
        if (i == j-1) {
            res.push_back(num);
            return;
        }
        for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {
            if (i != k && num[i] == num[k]) continue;
            swap(num[i], num[k]);
            recursion(num, i+1, j, res);
        }
    }
    vector<vector<int> > permuteUnique(vector<int> &num) {
        sort(num.begin(), num.end());
        vector<vector<int> >res;
        recursion(num, 0, num.size(), res);
        return res;
    }
};
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: num isn't passed by reference to `recursion()` - each call gets a brand new copy of the number array.

Comment: seems to me that the line  " if (i != k && num[i] == num[k]) continue; " creates a lot of duplicate checking,  simpler if (num[i] == num[k]) continue; would be better as the first go-through in that loop wouldnt go into recursion call,  also the  int j parameter is always num.size so you might want to remove it for simplicity

Comment: @user1316208 Without the `i!=k`, the first recursion (where nothing is changed / something is swapped with itself) won't happen => No result for it. `i!=k` is necessary.

Comment: @deviantfan it seems to me that the result will be obtained further in the for cycle. But maybe im wrong

Comment: @user1316208 Try it with 1 1 2 (manually, or code, what you like). There won't be any result (But maybe I am wrong too :))

Comment: @deviantfan Yep i tried it and it seems you were right, i didnt understand the algorithm properly.

Comment: @notmyfriend, why it is copied? Any more details are appreciated. :)

Comment: It's copied because the parameter type is `vector<int> num` as opposed to a reference (`vector<int>& num`) or pointer (`vector<int>* num`). In C, arrays are always passed as a pointer because you have no choice; the *only* information an "array variable" contains is the address of the start of the array, so there's no built-in mechanism by which a copy of an array could be produced. C++ classes do not have that drawback, and so can behave in ways that match that of basic types: passing a class by value works the same as passing an int, float, etc. by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @notmyfriend said in the comments, `num` is actually copied each function call.
So now it boils down to:

- Of all array values, select one to be the first one and place it there.
  That in a loop for each value one time, and then recursively:

  - Of all values after the first one, select one to be the first and place it there...

...and so on, combined with a check to filter out swaps where nothing changes, ie. filter out duplicates.

If `num` were a real reference, it won't work anymore (at least not without additional steps).
Eg. 1 1 2 is an easy conterexample, it would give the results:

```
112, 121, 211, 112, 121
```

ie. there are duplicates despite the check (and probably there
are examples where some permutations are not generated at all, too).

About the comment:

Per default, every normal function parameter in C++ is copied
(normal = without explicit reference symbol '&' etc.).
Maybe you're thinking of C-style arrays: Essentially, what is passed there is a pointer (to the first value). The pointer is copied, but both original and copied pointer point to the same memory location.

While the purpose of `std::vector` is (too) to contain an array, the vector itself is a single class object (which contains a pointer to the values somewhere). A class can define itself how it should be copied (with a copy constructor).
Technically, the vector class *could* implement copying as pointer copying, then it would have the same effect as passing the whole vector as reference; but the C++ creators wanted to keep the copy semantics, ie. that copying a container class should make a real copy with all values duplicated.
For non-copying, there are references already...

Comment: Thanks deviantfan, if it is copy by value. Then I understand. But why it is copied by value? I could be wrong but I think if we pass a vector if integer, it is passed by reference? No? More details are appreciated.

Comment: @LinMa See the addition in the answer.

Comment: Thanks deviantfan for clarification of behavior of passing a reference to a vector, I am wondering if making a real copy when passing a reference to a vector only for vector of integer, or vector of anything (saying a customized class object)? Thanks.

Comment: Everything is passed by value, unless you specify otherwise. In general, you should always pass classes by reference (a const reference if you don't need to modify the class in your function) unless you *specifically* need a copy of it (for example, in this algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find a solution written in Java. Sorry for not providing a solution in C++, I'm not using it for a long time. But the syntax would be similar.

Solution is using Backtracking (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)
Also I'm using hashset to check uniqueness, may be there is a solution which does not use any hashset type data structure, becase my solution is using extra memory in order to provide unique solutions.

Sample input and output;

```
input  :  [1, 1, 2]
output :  [1, 1, 2]
          [1, 2, 1]
          [2, 1, 1]
```

And the solution is;

```
public class permutation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        permutation p = new permutation();
        p.permute(new int[] { 1, 1, 2 });
    }

    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    private void permute(int[] arr) {
        set.clear();
        this.permute(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    }

    private void permute(int[] arr, int l, int r) {
        if (l == r) {
            String key = Arrays.toString(arr);
            if (set.contains(key))
                return;
            set.add(key);
            System.out.println(key);
        } else {
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
                swap(arr, l, i);
                permute(arr, l + 1, r);
                swap(arr, i, l);
            }
        }
    }

    private void swap(int[] arr, int l, int r) {
        int tmp = arr[l];
        arr[l] = arr[r];
        arr[r] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from the wrong language, OP has already a working solution (better than yours too), just not understanding it.